# How do I select values from a lookup table based on their time stamp?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `dayfile` containing the following variables:

```
Period   SubCode            EchoTime  PosX  PosY  PosZ
1   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:27 16.81 39.21 12.66
2   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:35 16.67 39.08 12.66
3   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:36 16.33 39.60 13.03
4   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:45 17.14 38.14 12.23
5   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:53 16.95 38.21 12.38
6   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:53 17.44 37.67 11.95
```

And I have another data frame called `probe.DOT1` that looks like this:

```
  DO.time.1m           DO.1m Temp.1m
1 2016-06-18 10:24:50  7.69   18.04
2 2016-06-18 11:24:50  7.54   19.12
3 2016-06-18 11:54:50  7.57   18.98
4 2016-06-18 12:24:50  9.51   19.88
5 2016-06-18 12:54:50  9.30   11.62
6 2016-06-18 13:24:50  8.81   11.54
```

I want to create a new column in `dayfile` called `O2` from `probe.DOT1$DO.1m` where `dayfile$EchoTime` is within the time range between two consecutive values of `probe.DOT1$Do.time.1m`, i.e. it should look something like this:

```
Period   SubCode            EchoTime  PosX  PosY  PosZ  O2
1   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:27 16.81 39.21 12.66  7.54
2   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:35 16.67 39.08 12.66  7.54
3   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:36 16.33 39.60 13.03  7.59
4   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:45 17.14 38.14 12.23  7.59
5   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:53 16.95 38.21 12.38  7.59
6   8753      13 2016-06-19 00:06:53 17.44 37.67 11.95  7.59
```

I have tried this:

```
dayfile$O2 <- probe.DOT1[dayfile$EchoTime < probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m &
dayfile$EchoTime > diff(probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m, lag = 1) , 'DO.1m']
```

But it gives me errors. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

*EDIT*

Here is some dput so you can recreate small portions of my files:

`dayfile`:

```
structure(list(Period = c(7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 
7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 
7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 
7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 7017, 
7017, 7017), SubCode = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20
), EchoTime = structure(c(1466249003, 1466249010, 1466249017, 
1466249025, 1466249032, 1466249039, 1466249046, 1466249053, 1466249060, 
1466249067, 1466249074, 1466249081, 1466249088, 1466249095, 1466249102, 
1466249109, 1466249116, 1466249123, 1466249130, 1466249137, 1466249144, 
1466249151, 1466249158, 1466249165, 1466249172, 1466249179, 1466249186, 
1466249193, 1466249200, 1466249207, 1466249214, 1466249221, 1466249228, 
1466249235, 1466249242, 1466249249, 1466249256, 1466249263, 1466249270, 
1466249277, 1466249284), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    PosX = c(14.69, 14.69, 14.69, 16.31, 14.94, 14.94, 14.85, 
    14.73, 16.64, 16.65, 16.7, 16.36, 16.38, 16.37, 16.41, 16.39, 
    16.12, 15.8, 16.33, 16.17, 16.32, 15.61, 15.5, 15.82, 16.68, 
    16.68, 16.68, 16.61, 16.68, 16.68, 11.39, 11.39, 16.68, 16.6, 
    16.6, 15.08, 15.08, 14.9, 14.81, 15.08, 15.15), PosY = c(36.98, 
    36.98, 36.98, 37.68, 36.9, 36.9, 36.96, 37.09, 37.19, 37.19, 
    37.01, 37.49, 37.47, 37.47, 37.45, 37.46, 37.75, 38.08, 38.06, 
    38.49, 38.06, 38.54, 38.39, 38.06, 37.16, 37.16, 37.16, 37.36, 
    37.16, 37.16, 40.09, 40.09, 37.16, 37.37, 37.37, 36.79, 36.79, 
    36.98, 36.94, 36.79, 36.73), PosZ = c(14.68, 14.68, 14.68, 
    15.67, 15.03, 15.03, 14.66, 14.88, 15.12, 15.22, 14.84, 15.28, 
    15.58, 15.48, 15.88, 15.68, 16.05, 15.91, 15.37, 15.64, 15.27, 
    16.1, 16.3, 16.33, 15.61, 15.61, 15.61, 15.8, 15.61, 15.61, 
    18.06, 18.06, 15.61, 15.7, 15.7, 15.13, 15.13, 15.3, 15.38, 
    15.13, 15.19)), .Names = c("Period", "SubCode", "EchoTime", 
"PosX", "PosY", "PosZ"), row.names = c(213387L, 213389L, 213391L, 
213393L, 213395L, 213397L, 213399L, 213401L, 213403L, 213405L, 
213407L, 213409L, 213411L, 213413L, 213415L, 213417L, 213419L, 
213421L, 213423L, 213425L, 213427L, 213429L, 213431L, 213433L, 
213435L, 213437L, 213439L, 213441L, 213443L, 213445L, 213447L, 
213449L, 213450L, 213452L, 213454L, 213456L, 213458L, 213460L, 
213462L, 213464L, 213466L), class = "data.frame")
```

`probe.DOT1`:

```
structure(list(DO.time.1m = structure(c(1466245490, 1466249090, 
1466250890, 1466252690, 1466254490, 1466256290, 1466258090, 1466259890, 
1466261690, 1466263490, 1466265290, 1466267090, 1466268890, 1466270690, 
1466272490, 1466274290, 1466276090, 1466277890, 1466279690, 1466281490
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), DO.1m = c(7.69, 
7.54, 7.57, 9.51, 9.3, 8.81, 8.71, 8.66, 8.19, 8.52, 8.79, 9.01, 
9.19, 9.39, 9.79, 9.82, 9.48, 9.5, 9.29, 9.38), Temp.1m = c(18.04, 
19.12, 18.98, 19.88, 11.62, 11.54, 12.24, 12.22, 12.32, 12.2, 
12.18, 12.16, 12.14, 11.8, 11.62, 11.68, 11.52, 11.32, 11.34, 
11.14)), .Names = c("DO.time.1m", "DO.1m", "Temp.1m"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please `dput(dayfile)` and `dput(probe.DOT1)` so it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: the diff returns 1 less element so you need `c(NA, diff(probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m, lag = 1))` but then with your sample data you still get numeric(0) returned

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for the tip - dput added.

Comment: I'm wondering if something like `tapply` would work - apply a function to each line in `dayfile` that compares the timestamp to those in `probe.DOT1` and identifies which `DO.1m` it corresponds to. Not sure how to code this though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah man... `fuzzyjoin` almost can solve this (which would be infinitely "eleganter"), but o well.

Here's my pipeline to do this w/out loops... but the dput you gave us is a bit crappy in that there was only 1 value properly *between* ranges... but let's see how it does on your real data.

```
## First create a df that contains all the timestamp info:
all <- data.frame(ts = unique(unlist(c(dayfile$EchoTime,probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m))))

## Now join both tables to this master record, fill in the blanks in 
## Period,SubCode,PosX,Y,Z, remove Temp.1m, remove useless rows, rename O2
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
all %>%
  left_join(dayfile,   by=c("ts"="EchoTime")) %>%
  left_join(probe.DOT1,by=c("ts" = "DO.time.1m")) %>%
  arrange(ts) %>%
  fill(Period,SubCode,PosX,PosY,PosZ) %>%
  select(-Temp.1m) %>%
  filter(!is.na(DO.1m)) %>%
  rename(O2=DO.1m)

# ts Period SubCode  PosX  PosY  PosZ   O2
# 1  2016-06-18 10:24:50     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA 7.69
# 2  2016-06-18 11:24:50   7017      20 16.38 37.47 15.58 7.54
# 3  2016-06-18 11:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 7.57
# 4  2016-06-18 12:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.51
# 5  2016-06-18 12:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.30
# 6  2016-06-18 13:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.81
# 7  2016-06-18 13:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.71
# 8  2016-06-18 14:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.66
# 9  2016-06-18 14:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.19
# 10 2016-06-18 15:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.52
# 11 2016-06-18 15:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 8.79
# 12 2016-06-18 16:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.01
# 13 2016-06-18 16:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.19
# 14 2016-06-18 17:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.39
# 15 2016-06-18 17:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.79
# 16 2016-06-18 18:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.82
# 17 2016-06-18 18:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.48
# 18 2016-06-18 19:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.50
# 19 2016-06-18 19:54:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.29
# 20 2016-06-18 20:24:50   7017      20 15.15 36.73 15.19 9.38
```

### *EDIT:*

To see the whole dataset with all the data together, use:

```
all %>%
  left_join(dayfile,   by=c("ts"="EchoTime")) %>%
  left_join(probe.DOT1,by=c("ts" = "DO.time.1m"))
```

In R, you can (and should) run every row one at a time...just to see what each row does. Do this by selecting "blocks of text"... from `all` to whatever. See how running what I have above shows you all the steps so far? You can do that with every other line in the pipeline too... so just select the block everything including the fill, then run:

```
all %>%
  left_join(dayfile,   by=c("ts"="EchoTime")) %>%
  left_join(probe.DOT1,by=c("ts" = "DO.time.1m")) %>%
  arrange(ts) %>%
  fill(Period,SubCode,PosX,PosY,PosZ)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it's not quite what I need. Your code pulls out values of x,y,z from `dayfile` and appends them to the observations in `probe.DOT1`. I need the code to do the opposite - DO values from `probe.DOT1` need to be appended to `dayfile`. To be explicit, I have a list of x,y,z coordinates of fish (`dayfile`) and I want to know what the dissolved oxygen (DO) was at each observation. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Yeah, I know what you were doing... I've had one or two outings w/ a DO/ORP/Tep/pH probe myself. And I'm gluing EVERYTHING together. Run my code one pipe at a time... for example, stop after the `arrange` command, but before the `%>%`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'one pipe at a time'!

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks! I didn't understand your code at first because (a) I've never used dplyr before and (b) I've never heard of pipelines. A quick Google search and I understand how powerful these are. I've edited your code slightly to fill the `DO.1m` column and filter NAs from the `PosX` column and it works perfectly on my real data. Half a million observations coded in a few seconds - awesome! Thanks so much, Amit!

Comment: The advantage of dplyr is not speed as much as the human readability. the `%>%` is pronounced "And then". As in: Do one AND THEN do that AND THEN do the third thing. It's how humans think and makes R much more friendly. :) Look for some vignettes.And don't forget to mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a double loop for this

```
dayfile$O2 <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(dayfile)) {
  for (j in 2:nrow(probe.DOT1)) {
    # between previous do time and before current do time
    if (dayfile$EchoTime[i] > probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m[j - 1] & dayfile$EchoTime[i] < probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m[j]) {
      dayfile$O2[i] <- probe.DOT1$DO.1m[j]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am hoping to avoid using loops as I have large data sets (0.5 million rows). I've tried your code on one of my files, and it works fine but it's still processing after 30 minutes.

Comment: Update - when I got into work this morning, it was still processing after 18 hours!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my problem based on the code from @Amit

```
all <- data.frame(ts = unique(unlist(c(dayfile$EchoTime, probe.DOT1$DO.time.1m))))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
all <- all %>%
  left_join(dayfile,   by=c("ts"="EchoTime")) %>%
  left_join(probe.DOT1,by=c("ts" = "DO.time.1m")) %>%
  arrange(ts) %>%
  fill(DO.1m) %>%
  select(-Temp.1m) %>%
  filter(!is.na(PosX)) %>%
  rename(O2=DO.1m) %>%
  arrange(Period, ts) 

dayfile$O2 <- all$O2
```

I changed @Amit's code slightly by filling `Do.1m` instead of the `dayfile` columns and then filtering out NAs from `PosX` instead of `DO.1m`. It works a treat!

Here is the output:

```
       Period SubCode            EchoTime  PosX  PosY  PosZ   O2
213387   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:23 14.69 36.98 14.68 7.69
213389   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:30 14.69 36.98 14.68 7.69
213391   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:37 14.69 36.98 14.68 7.69
213393   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:45 16.31 37.68 15.67 7.69
213395   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:52 14.94 36.90 15.03 7.69
213397   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:23:59 14.94 36.90 15.03 7.69
213399   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:06 14.85 36.96 14.66 7.69
213401   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:13 14.73 37.09 14.88 7.69
213403   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:20 16.64 37.19 15.12 7.69
213405   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:27 16.65 37.19 15.22 7.69
213407   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:34 16.70 37.01 14.84 7.69
213409   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:41 16.36 37.49 15.28 7.69
213411   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:48 16.38 37.47 15.58 7.69
213413   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:24:55 16.37 37.47 15.48 7.54
213415   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:02 16.41 37.45 15.88 7.54
213417   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:09 16.39 37.46 15.68 7.54
213419   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:16 16.12 37.75 16.05 7.54
213421   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:23 15.80 38.08 15.91 7.54
213423   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:30 16.33 38.06 15.37 7.54
213425   7017      20 2016-06-18 11:25:37 16.17 38.49 15.64 7.54
```